# HTTP delete with NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, http

Im doing a RESTful server on NodeJS and MongoDB but im stuck on the DELETE method, because im getting the error

```
"Argument passed in must be a single String of …modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3"
```

when trying to cast the req.body.listId into an ObjectId.

Here's my code:

```
router.delete('/', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('listcollection');
  var oId = new ObjectId(req.body.listId); //The exception is here

  collection.remove(
    {
      "_id": oId
    },function(err,doc){
        if (err) {
            res.json("There was a problem deleting the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
            res.json("Successfully deleted");
        }
    }
  );
});
```

Solved!:
The listId parameter was quoted ("58f8b2cc8cf726ca76551589") so I did an slice. Anyway I changed the param to be received in the URL, here's the code: Thanks!!

```
router.delete('/:listId', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('listcollection');

  var listId = req.params.listId;
  listId = listId.slice(1, listId.length - 1);

  var oId = new ObjectId(listId);

  collection.remove(
    {
      "_id": oId
    },function(err,doc){
        if (err) {
            res.json("There was a problem deleting the information to the database.");
        }
        else {
            res.json("Successfully deleted");
        }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Parameters for delete method should be passed only thru query string/URL itself not a body like post or put

Comment: Can you show us what your request body looks like? What did you post? It sounds like the contents of `req.body.listId` violate the restrictions for `ObjectId`. Additionally, as already mentioned, it would be more RESTful to specify the id in the URL, so your route would become `router('/:id')` and then you could access the id in express via the `req.params.id`.

Comment: The listId parameter was quoted ("58f8b2cc8cf726ca76551589") so I did an slice. Anyway I changed the param to be received in the URL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because `req.body.listId` does not follow the rule of `ObjectId` -- ObjectId is a string of 12 bytes (24 `0-9` or `a-f` characters, e.g. `"507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"`). What may go wrong is:

- `req.body.listId` is a plain number, not a String type, e.g. `89876`.
- `req.body.listId` is a String, but not follow the rule described above.

---

Although it is not RESTful, HTTP `DELETE` request with JSON body is totally OK. The Node.js server can receive the request and its body.

Comment: The listId parameter was quoted ("58f8b2cc8cf726ca76551589") so I did an slice. Anyway I changed the param to be received in the URL. Thanks!

Comment: @FernandoPerez The quote is just used to indicate it's a string type :)